# Error using Netflix on AppleTV

Tags: appletv

Recently I was watching a movie on Netflix on my pc with no problems.  I wanted to watch it on my AppleTV (2) I get an error saying

> Netflix is currently unavailable and to try back later.

I tried back later and got the same error.

Any ideas as to why I get this "Netflix is currently unavailable and to try back later" message?

Comment: Can you describe the recommendations that you tried? People reading this question should know what might not work if they suggest it to you.

Comment: Ah, I see that you have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pressed Menu And Down for about 6 - 10 seconds and left go to get the AppleTV to reboot.

Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs intermittently. Sometimes your solution will work, other times you might need to power cycle the ATV2 (give about 30 secs for cycle). If you have other streaming problems you might need to forward port 123 on your router (you shouldn't *have* to forward those ports, but I have done it when problems were extreme, and it fixed my issue).

Answer (score 1):

I see you resolved your question, but for completeness, it can also happen when AppleTV is not properly setup to the country you are currently on. I'm currently in Latin America and  had to change the country on Configuration/iTunes Store to make it work (it was on USA, now says Argentina).

Answer (score 1):

I had to reset my AppleTV to factory settings to get Netflix to work again.